# How to add automatically data to the missing days in historical stock prices?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, finance

I would like to write a python script that will check if there is any missing day. If there is it should take the price from the latest day and create a new day in data. I mean something like shown below. My data is in CSV files. Any ideas how it can be done?

Before:

```
MSFT,5-Jun-07,259.16
MSFT,3-Jun-07,253.28
MSFT,1-Jun-07,249.95
MSFT,31-May-07,248.71
MSFT,29-May-07,243.31
```

After:

```
MSFT,5-Jun-07,259.16
MSFT,4-Jun-07,253.28
MSFT,3-Jun-07,253.28
MSFT,2-Jun-07,249.95
MSFT,1-Jun-07,249.95
MSFT,31-May-07,248.71
MSFT,30-May-07,243.31
MSFT,29-May-07,243.31
```

My solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file/file.csv",names=list("abc")) # read string as file


cols = df.columns # store column order
df.b = pd.to_datetime(df.b) # convert col Date to datetime
df.set_index("b",inplace=True) # set col Date as index
df = df.resample("D").ffill().reset_index() # resample Days and fill values

df = df[cols] # revert order
df.sort_values(by="b",ascending=False,inplace=True) # sort by date
df["b"] = df["b"].dt.strftime("%-d-%b-%y") # revert date format
df.to_csv("data.csv",index=False,header=False) #specify outputfile if needed

print(df.to_string())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **pandas** library this operation can be made on a single line. But first we need to read in your data to the right formats:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

s = u"""name,Date,Close
MSFT,30-Dec-16,771.82
MSFT,29-Dec-16,782.79
MSFT,28-Dec-16,785.05
MSFT,27-Dec-16,791.55
MSFT,23-Dec-16,789.91
MSFT,16-Dec-16,790.8
MSFT,15-Dec-16,797.85
MSFT,14-Dec-16,797.07"""

#df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv") # read from file
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s)) # read string as file

cols = df.columns # store column order
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) # convert col Date to datetime
df.set_index("Date",inplace=True) # set col Date as index
df = df.resample("D").ffill().reset_index() # resample Days and fill values

df
```

Returns:

```
         Date  name   Close
0  2016-12-14  MSFT  797.07
1  2016-12-15  MSFT  797.85
2  2016-12-16  MSFT  790.80
3  2016-12-17  MSFT  790.80
4  2016-12-18  MSFT  790.80
5  2016-12-19  MSFT  790.80
6  2016-12-20  MSFT  790.80
7  2016-12-21  MSFT  790.80
8  2016-12-22  MSFT  790.80
9  2016-12-23  MSFT  789.91
10 2016-12-24  MSFT  789.91
11 2016-12-25  MSFT  789.91
12 2016-12-26  MSFT  789.91
13 2016-12-27  MSFT  791.55
14 2016-12-28  MSFT  785.05
15 2016-12-29  MSFT  782.79
16 2016-12-30  MSFT  771.82
```

Return back to csv with:

```
df = df[cols] # revert order
df.sort_values(by="Date",ascending=False,inplace=True) # sort by date
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%-d-%b-%y") # revert date format
df.to_csv(index=False,header=False) #specify outputfile if needed
```

Output:

```
MSFT,30-Dec-16,771.82
MSFT,29-Dec-16,782.79
MSFT,28-Dec-16,785.05
MSFT,27-Dec-16,791.55
MSFT,26-Dec-16,789.91
MSFT,25-Dec-16,789.91
MSFT,24-Dec-16,789.91
MSFT,23-Dec-16,789.91
...
```

Comment: I have data in csv files. Is there any easy way to convert this solution to take data from csv?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but I got `raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
ValueError: Unknown string format`

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm able to read the data from a string. Updated code I'm not very sure where your problem occurs.

Comment: My solution is in updated question, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you would need to iterate through your dataframe using nested for loops. That would look something like:

```
for column in df:
    for row in df:
        do_something()
```

To give you an idea, the

```
do_something()
```

part of your code would probably be something like checking if there was a gap between the dates. Then you would copy the other columns from the row above and insert a new row using:

```
df.loc[row] = [2, 3, 4]  # adding a row
df.index = df.index + 1  # shifting index
df = df.sort()  # sorting by index
```

Hope this helped give you an idea of how you would solve this. Let me know if you want some more code!

Answer (score 0):

This code uses standard routines.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

Input lines will have to be split on commas, and the dates parsed in two places in the main part of the code. I have therefore put this work in a single function.

```
def glean(s):
    msft, date_part, amount = s.split(',')
    if date_part.find('-')==1: 
        date_part = '0'+date_part
    date = datetime.strptime(date_part, '%d-%b-%y')
    return date, amount
```

Similarly, dates will have to be formatted for output with other pieces of data in a number of places in the main code.

```
def out(date,amount):
    date_str = date.strftime('%d-%b-%y')
    print(('%s,%s,%s' % ('MSFT', date_str, amount)).replace('MSFT,0', 'MSFT,'))

with open('before.txt') as before:
```

I read the initial line of data on its own to establish the first date for comparison with date in the next line.

```
previous_date, previous_amount = glean(before.readline().strip())
out(previous_date, previous_amount)
for line in before.readlines():
    date, amount = glean(line.strip())
```

I calculate the elapsed time between the current line and the previous line, to know how many lines to output in place of missing lines.

```
    elapsed = previous_date - date
```

`setting_date` is decremented from `previous_date` for the number of days that elapsed without data. One line is omitted for each day, if there were any.

```
    setting_date = previous_date
    for i in range(-1+elapsed.days):
        setting_date -= timedelta(days=1)
        out(setting_date, previous_amount)
```

Now the available line of data is output.

```
    out(date, amount)
```

Now `previous_date` and `previous_amount` are reset to reflect the new values, for use against the next line of data, if any.

```
    previous_date, previous_amount = date, amount
```

Output:

```
MSFT,5-Jun-07,259.16
MSFT,4-Jun-07,259.16
MSFT,3-Jun-07,253.28
MSFT,2-Jun-07,253.28
MSFT,1-Jun-07,249.95
MSFT,31-May-07,248.71
MSFT,30-May-07,248.71
MSFT,29-May-07,243.31
```

Comment: I get an error - `ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%d-%b-%y'` Maybe it would be easier to load data from csv files because at the moment I have my data in csv files. I added my source code to the updated question. Any suggestions what may be wrong?

Comment: You can use your csv files as they are, providing that they conform to the format indicated in your question. (All bets are off if they don't!) I was skirting the rules slightly in my use of that datetime format. The rules didn't catch me but they caught you. I've added a couple of lines to `glean` to deal with this in my edit. I've also change the output which was actually correct. I had put an earlier (incorrect) version in my answer.

Comment: This could be done with the csv module but it would be no easier, might be slightly more difficult to follow.

Comment: I still get `ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%d-%b-%y'`

Comment: My solution is in updated question, thank you for your help.